# Update global variables by using map reduce

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce

Assume I have this in pyspark:

```
def condi( x ):
    if x["age"] <= 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def add_count( x ):
    global aa
    aa += 1
    x["count"] += 10000
    return x

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(  master = 'spark://192.168.56.103:7077',appName = 'test' )

data = [{"age":1,"count":10},{"age":2,"count":20},{"age":3,"count":30}]

data = sc.parallelize( data )

global aa
aa = 0

k = data.map( lambda x : add_count( x ) if condi( x ) else x )

print( k.collect() )
print( aa )
```

Output like this :

```
[{'count': 10010, 'age': 1}, {'count': 10020, 'age': 2}, {'count': 30, 'age': 3}] # data
0 # aa
```

The global variable `aa` doesn't modify at all.

How could I modify global variables by using map reduce ?

Comment: *What* global variable `a`? I only see a global variable `aa`. Anyway, did you try to check if `add_count` actually gets called, for example by `print`ing a message there?

Comment: I don't think it will be available on all the executors. consider using broadcast variable- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=broadcast#pyspark.Broadcast

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Yes, add_count actually gets called !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `aa` as [Accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/accumulators.html), so it will be shared by all executors. Please use

```python
aa = sc.accumulator(0)
```

instead of

```python
aa = 0
```

After this change, the value printed out will be `2`.

Explanation: each executor uses its own local copy of variables. So adding +1 to one *copy* of `aa` on an executor does not change the value of `aa` on the driver. The statement `print( aa )` is executed on the driver and therefore does not see the changes on the executors.

You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40873538/2129801).

Comment: How could I do if I want to do multiply or divide ?

Comment: afaik, the plain vanilla accumulators only support `add`. For more operations, you would have to create your own [AccumulatorParam](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.AccumulatorParam) and implement a custom [addInPlace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.AccumulatorParam.addInPlace) method that would execute the multiplication or whatever is required. However I haven't done that so far...